# What is the term used to describe the space under a roof that joins two buildings?

Tags: terminology, architecture

Sometimes architects will take two tall (say 8-10 storey) buildings  that happen to be near each other, and build a glass roof between them.
Down on ground, the area which originally would have been a street, or 
alleyway or something, now becomes a quasi-outdoor, courtyard type
space where people can hang out and look up a roof/ceiling many storeys in the air.
What is the name for a space like this?
I think there are many terms which are used to describe this architectural feature. I just know there is one term in particular that - to me - describes it really well. So for example if you said to a friend

> "I'll meet you at the __________ between the two buildings"

the friend would know where you meant.
I keep thinking "atrium" or something like that?

Comment: Like this? http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/c145cf827d9042a0bf257350756f9181/glass-roof-between-two-buildings-dsseldorf-rhineland-north-rhine-westphalia-dggfnf.jpg

Comment: @Josh61 , nice find! yes.

Comment: If you are okay with shops on the sides it might be an [arcade](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arcade) 1.1

Comment: @Helmar yes, from looking around I think there are many terms which are used to describe this architectural feature. I just know there is one term in particular that - to me - describes it really well. So for example if you said to a friend "I'll meet you at the __________ between the two buildings" the friend would know where you meant.

Comment: Okay, so a more general designation for that architectuarl feature. It might be good to enter that example sentence in your question to clarify it for people who do not follow the comments.

Comment: @Helmar good point, question updated.

Comment: Not sure there  is a common term to describe that specific context, probably there is a technical one. On a colloquial basis you would probably refer to the arcade, square, open space etc. citing the site name or the shops that may be in the vicinity.

Comment: I think I'd call that an arcade even if there were no shops… but then I don't think I've ever seen such a structure without there being shops on either side.

Comment: The first word that popped in to my mind was "breezeway", but in my mind this describes something more modest than what seems to be being considered here.

Comment: In Minneapolis,Minnesota there's a network of enclosed glass walkways connecting buildings called the "skyway". It's not at the top of the buildings though is above street level. https://www.minneapolis.org/map-transportation/minneapolis-skyway-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google images of ***[covered courtyard](https://www.google.com/search?q=covered+courtyard&biw=788&bih=419&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE7-Ca14zOAhWCoD4KHX8CBbAQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1)***, you get many images like this:

[image]

Many of these images show an area between two large buildings, with a latticed glass roof. Maybe this is enough to convince you that *covered courtyard* works as a description.

More specifically, such a glass-covered courtyard is called an [***atrium***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtyard#Historic_use), which is probably why this word sprang to your mind. Many of the spaces depicted in the linked images might be called atriums.

Further, if you google "[atrium between buildings](https://www.google.com/search?q=atrium&biw=788&bih=419&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjip-3c2IzOAhVDPz4KHZO4BKkQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=atrium%20between%20buildings)" you get many results which depict spaces like the ones you describe. This should convince you that *atrium* is, if not the perfect word, a very good one.

The following photo, for instance, shows an atrium *between* the IBM Building and Trump Tower:

[image]

Comment: thanks. yes the non technical term "covered courtyard" works nicely. But as embarassing as this is to admit - atrium is the term I was "looking" for and you were 100% right. atrium wikipedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrium_(architecture)

Comment: This is very interesting to me. I would never call such a structure an atrium—and I wouldn’t have imagined anyone else would, either. An atrium to me is _inside_ a building, or at least enclosed on all sides by building(s). I would be quite confused if you were talking about this type of arcade-like structure and calling it an atrium: I’d start wondering what place exactly you were talking about.